# nz-select with reative-form can clear after selected in version 7.0.0-rc3, but in version 7.0.0 cannot clear it

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

In Ng-Zorro-Antd version 7.0.0-rc3, I can clear nz-select option with Reactive-form after selected, but in version 7.0.0 stable, I cannot clear it with reactive-form.
Any idea please, help me, please.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

have you try to specify the [nzAllowClear] of the nz-select component? Also check the control has controlName in the reactive form